# Why does argc exist/why does env NOT have simething similar?

Tags: unix, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

I was reading here: http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/startup.html#st

Apparently, the stack layout for ELF binaries is like this:

```
argc          Number of arguments, which is the size of argv  
argv[0]       Program name
------------
argv[1]       Arguments that get passed to the program
...
argv[argc-1]
------------
NULL
------------
env[0]       Environmental variables
...
env[n]
-----------
NULL
```

There are two things to notice here, and I think they are a bit inconsistent.

1. Both argv and env are NULL terminated.
2. Only argv has a separate variable for the size.

Since they are NULL terminated, `argc` is strictly speaking not necessary, even if it can make some things a bit easier. Like that you don't have to go through the whole array to find the size. But these benefits also apply for `env`.

What's the rationale here? Why did they choose different approaches?

Answer (score 2):

I have no special insight into the minds of early Unix designers.  But for one thing, there are plenty of situations where you want to know the number of command line arguments, e.g. `if (argc < 3) usage();`.  But I can't think of any situation where you actually care about how many variables are set in the environment.  It's understood that the user may have set any number of environment variables which aren't relevant to your program, and that your program should just ignore them.  So whether there are 5 or 500 entries in the environment array is not something your program should care about; you should just look for the ones that you have documented as having an effect on your program.

As such, the only reason for having an `envc` variable would be to do something like

```c
int i;
for (i = 0; i < envc; i++) {
    if (strncmp(env[i], "FROB=", strlen("FROB=")) == 0) {
        frob();
    }
}
```

But that is just as easily written as

```c
char **p;
for (p = env; *p; p++) {
    if (strncmp(*p, "FROB=", strlen("FROB=")) == 0) {
        frob();
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if `argc` weren't provided, then something like `if (argc < 3) usage();` would require several more lines of code.

So having `argc`, which technically not necessary, is convenient; while having `envc` would be truly redundant.